# Transform a dataframe without looping?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to analyse and transform the following DataFrame

```
import random
import string
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate example dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['Name']=[str(x) for x in np.random.choice(['a','b','c'],10)]
df['Cat1']=[str(x) for x in np.random.choice(['x',''],10)]
df['Cat2']=[str(x) for x in np.random.choice(['x',''],10)]
df['Cat3']=[str(x) for x in np.random.choice(['x',''],10)]

df.head(10)
```

This produces a DataFrame like this:

[Sample DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZevVP.png)

The task is to count the 'x' in columns Cat1, Cat2, Cat3 for each unique entry in column 'Name'. This can be achieved wth help ofthe groupby() function:

```
grouped=df.groupby(['Name'])
dfg=grouped['Cat1','Cat2','Cat3'].sum()
dfg
```

[Result of analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl0Uz.png)

And the result is this almost what I wanted. Now, I needed to replace the 'x' by a number, e.g., 'xxxx' by 4, 'x' by 1, and so forth. The solution uses a loop over all columns:

```
for col in range(0,len(dfg.columns)):
    dfg[dfg.columns[col]]=list(map(lambda x: len(x), dfg[dfg.columns[col]]))
dfg
```

[Final result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDWgJ.png)

Now, I wonder how I can avoid that loop and achieve the same final result?
Thanks a lot for sharing your ideas and guidance.

Comment: Just added the correct screenshot of the final result.

Comment: I think just `dfg.applymap(len)`, though not sure that's the most performant

Comment: Yes, cool, ALollz, your solution works. Thanks a lot for your swift reply, appreciated.

Comment: I think Scott Boston's answer is the better way to go, since it directly counts the matches and avoids the applymap. This method is really particular to just one character matches and will give false counts, since it will also count something like `'y'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df.set_index('Name').eq('x')\
  .groupby('Name')['Cat1','Cat2','Cat3'].sum()\
  .astype(int).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Name  Cat1  Cat2  Cat3
0    a     5     3     4
1    b     1     1     0
2    c     1     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you, Scott. Very elegant, just a "one-liner".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your source of data, this could be easily solved by replacing the "x" with a 1 and setting the empty cells to 0. So you also had to change the datatype of the column to integer.

Calling `sum()` then on your group will already give you the numeric answer.

Comment: Thank you, stekepego, for sharing your approach.